# AWS SSL certificate for EC2 is invalid

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, amazon-route53

I used AWS certificate manager to create and validate wildcard SSL certificate for my domain (e.g. *.mydomainname.com).   After that, I associated my certificate with load balancer and modified A record in Route 53 to route traffic to load balancer.

The browser tells me that certificate is invalid, I checked on https://cheapsslsecurity.com/ssltools/ssl-checker.php and it seems that certificate is OK.

Hosted zone in Route 53 looks like this:[image]

What is the problem here? Do I need to wait for some time?

What bothers me is that A record (first one on the screenshot) routes to load balancer that has .amazonaws.com domain and certificate is for *.mydomainname.com (A record name is mydomainname.com and the CNAME at the bottom is [www.mydomainname.com](http://www.mydomainname.com)).

Comment: Is that certificate also valid for `mydomainname.com`? A certificate for `*.mydomainname.com` is valid for e.g. `www.mydomainname.com` but not for `mydomainname.com` by itself. You'd need to add the latter as an "additional name" explicitly when creating the certificate.

Comment: You didn't hide all the references to your domain name in that screenshot. I went to your domain and the `www` address works, but not the root domain. You should have added two domain names to the SSL certificate, the root domain `example.com` and either `www.example.com` or `*.example.com`. It looks like you only added `*.example.com`

Comment: The error is due to mismatch between your certificate and the domain name you are accessing with. It looks like when you ordered the certificate you didn't include additional domain mydomainname.com. So when browsing with something like www.mydomainname.com would work fine but mydomainname.com would give certificate error. You can add additional domain name as mydomainname.com along with *.mydomainname.com while ordering SSL and it should work fine then.

Comment: You are right, thanks! Do I need to repeat the whole process of creating a certificate or I can edit the existing one?

Comment: You can't edit the existing certificate, you'll need to repeat the process.